# Container View Controller Examples

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios5

Can anyone point me to any good examples of creating a Custom View Controller as a Container View Controller? The only documentation I can find is a couple of paragraphs in the [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller). I feel I need a little more information than that and an example implementation would be nice. Google has turned up nothing at all.

I am specifically interested in the method:

```
transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:
```

Comment: Did you find other sources for this other than the one hypercrypt mentioned?

Comment: Not yet. I'm going to have another dig later today if I have time. It seems bizarre that there would be so little information about it given how important and useful it is. I wonder if it's buggy and will be better documented when it's improved.

Comment: This is extremely confusing to me to. For example, the view can only have one embeded controller. What about if you want to switch the controller on that container view?

Comment: @JanakNirmal Much obliged.

Comment: can i hide container view

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The best thing I have found so far is the WWDC 2011 Session Video [Session 102 - Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102).

Comment: Ditto. It's not my favorite demo code example, but it does properly implement VC containers as well as memory management -- it's really important that your child view controllers get released when they are no longer visible.

Comment: Unfortunately, the demo for how to use ContainerViewController didn't work because he didn't have email setup on his iPad :-(

Comment: Does that session has code sample?

Comment: do you have the sample code now, i need it because i have tried a lot but no solute yet.

Answer (score 37):

In addition to the WWDC Session Video [Session 102 - Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102T) that hypercrypt already mentioned, [Apple WWDC 2012 session on "The Evolution of View Controllers on iOS"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) also covers this topic and the example code is part of the sample code package:

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_sample_code/wwdc_2012_session_code.dmg

There's also an example here:
https://github.com/toolmanGitHub/stackedViewControllers

Comment: +1 mentioning where to get that damned code package. I've been looking through it.

Comment: +1 again, why o why can't Apple put the WWDC sessions code on their member pages?

Comment: +1, Would you mind sharing, how to get this source code path ?

Comment: @JanakNirmal which source code are you having trouble getting? To get the WWDC code just follow the dmg link and login with your apple developer id.

Answer (score 17):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // I put self in a Navigation VC so we can use its right navigationbar 
    // item for triggering the transition
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
     [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit 
                                                    target:self 
                                                    action:@selector(button:)] 
                                                                  autorelease];

    // create test1 and test2 instance (subclass UIViewController and 
    // also need to define their own nibs)
    vc1 = [[test1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"test1" bundle:nil];
    vc2 = [[test2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"test2" bundle:nil];

    //add to the container vc which is self    
    [self addChildViewController:vc1];
    [self addChildViewController:vc2];

    //the entry view (will be removed from it superview later by the api)
    [self.view addSubview:vc1.view];
}
```

this IBAction triggers the transition between two VCs:

```
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    [self transitionFromViewController:vc1 
                      toViewController:vc2 
                              duration:0.5    
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown 
                            animations:nil 
                            completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This is a great example. But the memory management in this case can be improved: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8453677/849616 for more suitable solution.

Comment: Not that you're wrong. But [self addChildViewController:vc1];
 doesn't make sense. The Container VC may have SEVERAL Container View Controllers.

Comment: @Vive I have reached a point in my project where I am concerned about memory management.  Could you tell me what particularly the link you posted does better in terms of memory management? I am very new and have a hard time seeing the discrepancies

Answer (score 11):

I found this example very useful for me

http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

And they have source on github:

https://github.com/mluton/EmbeddedSwapping

Answer (score 10):

Could this:

http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.com/2011/08/writing-high-quality-view-controller.html

Be enough for your needs?

Comment: Actually I had already found that, but unfortunately it is written about Ios4, but 5 has made significant changes. Apple now explicitly support creating custom View Controller Containers, though they don't seem to want to help us work out how to use them. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you show me where they say that. Not doubting you, just curious, because I have been struggling with that too.

Comment: No worries. I looked through the code for his container classes and none of them use any of the following methods: addChildViewController:,
removeFromParentViewController,
transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:,
willMoveToParentViewController: and 
didMoveToParentViewController: Which are all mentioned in the updated ios5 Documentation for UIViewController.

Answer (score 8):

don't know if this is a "good" example, but you can get a free Container ViewController from https://bitbucket.org/javieralonso/jaacordeonviewcontroller/overview

It's a full accordion metaphor container view controller

Comment: Nice find. That looks useful.

Answer (score 3):

These are my favorite (iOS7-ready) tutorial / examples on the subject (all three have source code available on github):

[View Controller Containment](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html)

[Custom Container View Controller Transitions](http://www.objc.io/issue-12/custom-container-view-controller-transitions.html)

[Interactive Custom Container View Controller Transitions](http://www.iosnomad.com/blog/2014/5/12/interactive-custom-container-view-controller-transitions)

And then, of course, Apple offers a whole write-up on the subject which I find invaluable:

[Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)