# Proper usage of transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I can't seem to find a good example on how to use `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:` properly.

Is this correct? (assuming I want to swap a VC with another)

```
// Assume fromVC and toVC view controllers are defined and fromVC is already added as a child view controller
[self addChildViewController:toVC];

[self transitionFromViewController:fromVC toViewController:toVC duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:NULL completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [fromVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [fromVC removeFromParentViewController];
    [toVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}];
```

The documentation isn't that clear about when to call what:

> The **addChildViewController:** method calls the
>   **willMoveToParentViewController:** method of the view controller to be
>   added as a child before adding it, but it does not call the
>   **didMoveToParentViewController:** method. The container view controller
>   class must call the **didMoveToParentViewController:** of the child view
>   controller after the transition to the new child is complete or, if
>   there is no transition, immediately after calling the
>   **addChildViewController:** method.
>
> Likewise, it is is the responsibility of the container view controller
>   to call the **willMoveToParentViewController:** method before calling the
>   **removeFromParentViewController:** method. The
>   **removeFromParentViewController:** method calls the
>   **didMoveToParentViewController:** method of the child view controller.

Another thing is, how do you use the animations block in this case? Notice in the above code I just put `NULL`. (I am familiar with block per se, I am just not sure what to put exactly in this one)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I've implemented this sort of thing similarly in the past. But, I would move `-willMoveToParentViewController:` outside the completion block since that view controller should be notified before it gets moved (i.e., by the time the completion block has run, `fromVC` has already had its parent VC set to `nil`. So all in all, something like this:

```
[self addChildViewController:toVC];
[fromVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

[self transitionFromViewController:fromVC toViewController:toVC duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [fromVC removeFromParentViewController];
    [toVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}];
```

In terms of animations, you should never set this parameter to `NULL`, according to the method documentation. If you have no view properties you want to animate, then you can simply pass it an empty block `^{}`. Basically this parameter is used for animating properties of your views in your view hierarchy during the transition. The list of animatable properties can be found in [the UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) under the "Animations" heading. As an example, say you don't want your whole view handled by `fromVC` to cross dissolve, but only want one subview in its view hierarchy named `subview1` to fade out. You can do this using the animations block:

```
[self addChildViewController:toVC];
[fromVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

[self transitionFromViewController:fromVC 
                  toViewController:toVC
                          duration:0.3
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                        animations:^{
                                       [subview1 setAlpha:0.0];
                                   }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                       [fromVC removeFromParentViewController];
                                       [toVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                                   }];
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! Have you also implemented the animations block in `transitionFromViewController`?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the animations block as well. Sorry, I missed that the first time reading through your question.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I am actually trying to replicate the default sliding from left/right transition similar to UINavigationController (I can't use UINavigationController as is, unfortunately, hence this post). I don't see any built-in transition that can do this, I guess I have to do it manually by positioning the views side-by-side and moving the frame together?

Comment: That's definitely one possible way of doing it. I haven't tried it myself, but I hope it works for you. If you're interested in replicating `UINavigationController` functionality, you may want to hold your views in a stack data structure. You could implement push and pop methods by using the `-transitionFromViewController...` method.

Comment: What happened to the shouldRotateToOrientation support in child VCs?

Comment: @rwyland um...i don't know? what do you mean?

Comment: `willMoveToParentViewController` called just before the view controller is added or removed from a container view controller. It should be called in completion block just before `removeFromParentViewController`

Comment: @zxcat Sorry, but nope. The removal happens in the -transistionFromViewController method, thus -willMove should be called before this and not during the completion. The WWDC 2011 session 102 slides show that the way written above is correct.

Comment: @Sean, you don't necessary need to remove VC while transition to other. `transistionFromViewController` removes the first view controller’s **view** from the **view hierarchy**. But `removeFromParentViewController` and `willMoveToParentViewController` are about adding/removing the given view controller as a child. You can have several child VC at a time.

Comment: @zxcat Correct, but the framework expects the view to still be in the hierarchy when `-willMove` gets called. Therefore, it goes before the `-transistionFrom` method. Again, this is exactly how apple explains to do it in their examples and documentation.

Comment: @Sean, but what if I don't want to remove VC from my container children after transition and only want to swap VCs? Like here: http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2012/09/container-view-controllers-parent-view.html

Comment: @Sean, ok, now I see the example above is wrong (but works fine). The documentation point all children must be visible. Thanks for helping me to understand this better. But why `-willMove` and `-addChild` do not build into `-transitionFrom`, if they are required actions?

Comment: @zxcat A couple of reasons: 1) it gives you more flexibility in terms of what code your container vc will run in between `-willMove` and `-didMove`. 2) there are other places besides `-transitionFrom` where your container VC will want to call the callbacks methods (e.g., when putting the very first contained view into the view hierarchy you need to call `-addChild` without calling `-transitionFrom`)

Comment: Can you do interactive transitions with transitionFromViewController:?