# ChildViewController view entering and then disappears

Tags: ios, childviewcontroller

I have a view controller in which there is a button and a window.

By pressing the button, the view in the window should change.

The view in the window is another ViewController and its view.

When pressing on the button, all the methods of `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` , `viewDidAppear` run.

However, after `viewDidAppear` runs, the view disappears, without running `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear`

The view does appear for a second before this happens, and all the elements of it are intialized, if I pause the run with the debug window, and po any of the UI elements, they are not null.

Why could this be happening ?

Here is my code for adding the view:

```
    if(![self.childViewControllers containsObject:_detailsContainer]){

    _detailsContainer.view.frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
    [_detailsContainer willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:_detailsContainer];
    UIViewController *currentViewController = [_mainSource viewControllerForContentAtIndex:self.pageIndex];
    [self transitionFromViewController:currentViewController toViewController:_detailsContainer duration:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:NULL completion:^(BOOL finished){

     [_detailsContainer didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    }];
}
```

Here is my `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` of the child view controller:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(self.isEditingDetails){
        [self setUserDetails:[self.userSettings getUserDetails]];
    }

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    LogInfo(@"details view did appear");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is happening due to a few UIViewController containment issues.

When you call `[self addChildViewController:_detailsContainer]` the system will automatically call `[_detailsConter willMoveToParentViewController:self]`.  However you will have to call `[currentViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil]` before your transition.

Also you have to call `[currentViewController removeFromParentViewController]` in your completion block of your animation.

see this answer for an example of how to use `transitionFromViewController...` [Proper usage of transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453653/proper-usage-of-transitionfromviewcontrollertoviewcontrollerdurationoptionsa?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: actually calling currentController removeFromParentViewController is not what i need because i want to keep the current controller (as it is permanent) and the new controller is just a swapin at the click of a button

Comment: It might be worth trying to do this without using `transitionFromViewController` since that would generally replace the existing.  You can just use a normal UIView `animateWithDuration` animation to animate in your new ViewController instead of using the transition methods.