# Navigation Bar Blinks When Animating for the First Time

Tags: objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, uiviewanimation

I have created my own tabbarcontroller of sorts, but am having an issue with animation. When I animate the views on tab click, the navigation bar turns completely black (should be red), then blinks back to red after the animation completes. My setup and code is below.

(Answers in either swift or objective-c are helpful since the tranlastion is easy)

Thanks in advance!

[image]

red: Navigation Bar

blue: Navigation Display View

grey: Tab Bar

burgundy: Tab Bar Display View (This is the part being transitioned/animated)

I transition/animate between my views with the below code.

```
 //Handles selection of a tab bar item
    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {

        //Get controller for transition
        var selectedController = self.controllers[item.tag];

        //Only transition for new view
        if(self.childViewControllers[0] as UIViewController != selectedController!){
            //Prepare for controller transition
            selectedController!.viewWillAppear(false)
            self.currViewController?.viewWillDisappear(false)
            self.currViewController?.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)

            //Set new controller with animation
            selectedController!.view.frame = self.displayView.frame
            if(transitionAnimated){
                UIView.transitionFromView(self.displayView, toView: selectedController!.view, duration: self.animationDuration, options: self.animationOptions, completion: {finished in
                        self.setNewController(selectedController!)
                        self.animationCompletion(finished)
                })
            }
            else{
                self.displayView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.view.addSubview(selectedController!.view)
                setNewController(selectedController!);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(self.childViewControllers[0].isKindOfClass(UINavigationController)){
                (self.childViewControllers[0] as UINavigationController).popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked into using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` for custom tab bar controller animations? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning_Protocol/. Nevermind, I just realized you made your own tab bar controller so the above probably won't help you.

Comment: I'm betting you're not sending all of the correct transition messages at the right times. Why not just [use `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8453677/1445366)?

Comment: @AaronBrager When I use transitionFromViewController, the view is not a subview of my displayView. My displayView shrinks and grows dependent on whether the tab bar is hidden or displayed (there are utility methods that animate the frame of the tab bar and the frame of the displayView). The resulting view controller when using transitionFromViewController covers the tab bar when displayed. If you can provide a fix for that, then I'm game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar problem with UINavigationController and this fixed it, try it:

Just before this line:

`UIView.transitionFromView(self.displayView, toView: selectedController!.view, duration: self.animationDuration, options: self.animationOptions, completion: {finished in`

Add the selectedController.view into the view hierarchy like this (Sorry **Obj-C** code)
`[self.displayView.superview addSubview:selectedController.view];`

Let me know if it works :) GOOD LUCK!

Comment: That worked. I don't know why, but it did. Can you explain why this stops the blinking nav bar?

Comment: I believe (I'm not sure It was just an hypothesis) that the problem is that the transition is using a snapshot of the view layer (presentationLayer) and that the view itself is not added to the view hierarchy, and as the navigationBar is rendered only when the view is actually added to the view hierarchy so it can access the "appearance proxy" settings it is not rendered on the moment when the transition starts.
That was my initial hypothesis, my test worked out but that doesn't mean my hypothesis was ok :(

Comment: Wow - I've tried so many variants to make this work without the blinking nav bar and nothing worked until this.  I also don't get it, but thank you for finding it!

Answer (score 1):

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        guard let fromView = selectedViewController?.view, let toView = viewController.view else
        {
            return false
        }

        if fromView != toView
        {
            fromView.superview!.addSubview(toView)
            UIView.transition(from: fromView, to: toView, duration: 0.15, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, completion: nil)
        }

        return true
    }
```

This worked for me!!!

Comment: To improve your answer, add some more comments/description of your code.

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened because I had a view behind the tabbar. when I made the view hidden at the time of the animation it solved the problem