# UITabbar Tab change animation show black glitch at time of transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitabbar, catransition

I am working with UITabBarController in which i have added transition when user switch tabs and it is working fine in iOS 8 but it iOS 9 it is showing black color at the time of transition.

Below is the code which i am using right now.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSInteger destinationViewControllerIndex = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    if ([self selectedIndex]==destinationViewControllerIndex) {
        // If Source and Destination Controller both are same return YES
        return YES;
    }
    // Push Animation when tabbar change
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    if ([self selectedIndex]>destinationViewControllerIndex) {
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    }else{
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    }
    [animation setDuration:0.35];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                              kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
    [self.view.window.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"fadeTransition"];

    return YES;
}
```

[image: It's look like this when user switch the tabs]

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it this way,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64888893/1002338

Answer (score 2):

I saw something very similar to this with some custom transition animations in iOS 9.

In the end, the solution was to disable translucency (self.tabBar.translucent = NO;) on the UITabBar object.