# IOS: UIView ever visible

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my app I want to set a UIView (called "functionView") ever visible in my app, and when I change view controller it should stay ever in its position.
I show you an example:

[image]

as you can see view function is ever in its position and it shouldn't change its position.

Can I do set this view from appDelegate? and how I can control it? Can I use a class (subclass of UIView)?

**IMPORTANT: it shouldn't be a tab bar but a view that with animation can move over view controller

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add subview to the main window of the application instead of the root viewController:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
//...
    [window addSubview:functionView];
//...
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a container view controller, which contains the functionview, and a view controller for the first and second views

you will need to manage the navigation/transition logic inside this view controller

this question has a link to a good WWDC video and a blog post about this: [Container View Controller Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755498/container-view-controller-examples)