# UIViewController with a UIView with replaceable content

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UISegmentControl` with 3 buttons/segments.

If I place a smaller `UIView` in the main view in the storyboard. Can I display content from 3 other `UIViewController` classes in this `UIView` depending on the `UISegmentControl` current segment?

I have to ask because just read something about not displaying another `UIViewController` in a `UIViewController`. And this is the scene I'm working on:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/80427098@N07/7859459430/in/photostream

So if my picture scene is a bad way of doing it, my question is:

Is there another way of displaying the content of `UIViewController` 1,2 and 3 according to the `UISegmentControl`?

I am stuck so I need some quick guidelines on how to do this in an approved and working way, as the 3 scenes are very different to each other.

**Brainstorming:**

- Placing 3 `UIViews` in the `UIViewController` scene overlaying each other and make one of them "on top" according to the `UISegmentControl`.
- Make a long un-scrollable `UIScrollView` with the content from 1,2,3 and jump up and down in the `UIScrollView` to given coordinates according to the `UISegmentControl`

I don't want to get stuck again so please tell me the easiest way of this, I just need some hints..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for in this case is a [container view controller.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW17) Here's also an article about them [Subjective Objective-C - container view controllers](http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.com/2011/08/writing-high-quality-view-controller.html) and another SO article relating to them here [Container View Controller Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755498/container-view-controller-examples)