# Subviews management in view hierarchy in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, subview

In my view i added 4 UIButtons at bottom (something like tab bar application) and when I click on any button I added their respective subviews through add subview method , and when user click on another button a new subview is added on that view and so on. I am sure this is not a right way to do this task.
so kindly suggest the way i could handle this situation while taking memory management into consideration.

Comment: Why not using UITabbarController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in two ways :

1. Add subview and then remove old subview when click on other button
2. Add all subview first time and then show and hide them.

This is the proper way for memory management.

Comment: Can you please give any sample code of doing it through first approach,i can't follow second approach as my view are not static.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIViewController Containment`,
The best thing I have found so far is the WWDC 2011 Session Video 
[Session 102 - Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102).

[Container View Controller Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755498/container-view-controller-examples/11600974#11600974)